# jQuery slideUp not working correctly.

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, slideup

I have an issue concerning the slideUp() method. It works only for the last element (Panel 3). The first two slide down and I have no idea why.. Please keep in mind that I just started with jQuery and I'm really a newbie.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.panel').on('click', function() {
        $(this).slideUp(600);
    });

});
```

And here is the JSfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/py4tfq3f/2/

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `display:inline-block` from the `panel div` to `float:left`,it solves the issue.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/py4tfq3f/3/)**

CSS:

```
.panel {
    margin: 50px 0 0 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the issue. Quite strange. Can you explain to me why does this happens if you have the time? Thanks for the solutions also! :)

Comment: Your answer is life saver for me